# Travel insurance required for Abu Dhabi?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, insurance, uae, pakistan, visitor

I am a citizen of Pakistan, and intend to travel to Abu Dhabi on a 30-day single-entry visa. My duration of stay is 3 days.

Is it mandatory to have travel insurance for me and my family? I got my visas.

Comment: I do not know whether it is required but it is always good to have travel insurance and it is cheap compared to most other costs of traveling.

Comment: Travel insurance is highly recommended. Sometimes a journey bought on a credit card will have travel insurance from the card issuer, but the cover usually isn't as comprehensive.

Comment: Note: countries may requires health insurance (not "travel insurance", but the later may include the first), so that in case of problems (accident, or health) somebody (but not the taxpayers) will pay. I would expect such requirement at visa-time.

Comment: thanks for guidance